# Extension of a struct in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, extension-methods, objective-c-category

I have an extension (of `SCNVector3`) in Swift like this:

```
extension SCNVector3 {

    // some functions extending SCNVector3 here....

}
```

I want to convert this extension to Objective-C. I know that the equivalent of extensions in ObjC is 'categories' but it doesn't seem possible to create a category on a struct like `SCNVector3`.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnvector3

Comment: There is no equivalent to Swift structs in Objective C. You should implement the extension's methods as C functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May you give more details on how to proceed ? Thanks a lot !

Comment: I've wrote an example as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent to Swift structs in Objective C. You should implement the extension's methods as C functions. For example computing the length of a vector:

```
inline SCNVector3 ExtSCNVector3Subtract(SCNVector3 inA, SCNVector3 inB) {
    return SCNVector3Make(inA.x - inB.x, inA.y - inB.y, inA.z - inB.z);
}

inline float ExtSCNVector3Length(SCNVector3 inA) {
    return sqrtf(inA.x * inA.x + inA.y * inA.y + inA.z * inA.z);
}
```

How you name the functions is entirely up to your taste. You call it as follows:

```
SCNVector3 a = ...;
SCNVector3 a = ...;
float distance = ExtSCNVector3Length(ExtSCNVector3Subtract(a, b));
```

Comment: That seems great ! So, I should create a .c file and corresponding .h file ? With a specific name ? And then, how do I do in order to do so that the compiler understands that these extented functions extends SCNVector3 ? Thanks !!!

Comment: If you declare the function as `inline`you need no .c file. For the compiler there is no need for that. Its just an ordinary C function, and you have to call it like other functions, too.

Comment: I have got the following extending function:  func distance(from vector: SCNVector3) -> Float {
        let distanceX = self.x - vector.x
        let distanceY = self.y - vector.y
        let distanceZ = self.z - vector.z
        
        return sqrtf((distanceX * distanceX) + (distanceY * distanceY) + (distanceZ * distanceZ))
    } I don't see how it can work if I convert it to Obj C and put it anywhere in my code. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I am going to try this. Will tell you . Thanks.